# Spring JMS Using ActiveMQ Server : Not Able to make onMessage of Lister transnational

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-transactions

**Through below Class i am getting message from active mq server :-**

```
 package com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.consumerqueue.impl;

    import javax.jms.JMSException;
    import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
    import javax.jms.Session;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.consumerqueue.ICibPublicationConsumer;
    import com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.model.ProductEvent;

    @Component
    public class CibPublicationConsumerImpl implements ICibPublicationConsumer {

        private static int count = 0;


        @Override
        public void onMessage(ObjectMessage message, Session session) throws JMSException {
            if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {

                ProductEvent event = (ProductEvent) message.getObject();

                System.out.println("EventId:" + event.getEventId());

                count++;

                if (count % 2 == 0) {

                    throw new IllegalStateException("Message type not supported");
                }


            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Message type not supported");

            }

        }
    }
```

**This is applicationContext.xml file of spring which i used to configure JMS template and JMS container.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

        <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
            <property name="trustAllPackages" value="true" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
            <constructor-arg name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></constructor-arg>
            <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="myqueue"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageListener"
        class="com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.consumerqueue.impl.CibPublicationConsumerImpl" />
        <bean id="jmsContainer"
            class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
            <property name="destinationName" value="myqueue" />
            <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
        </bean>

        <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.consumerqueue.impl"></context:component-scan>

    </beans>
```

**Below is main class which invoking my listener class to read message from queue :-**
        package com.orange.obsit.sando.cibinternational.consumerqueue;

```
    import org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

    public class CibPublicationConsumerImplTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

            try {
                // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            ((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx).close();

        }
        enter code here

    }
```

I want my listener to persist the message in case of any exception is being thrown.
Meaning that after listener is reading queue there is any error in further flow than transaction is rolled back and my data persist in queue.

Could anyone help me to do so ?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what is the code in the interface `ICibPublicationConsumer`.  Generally, to make a message listener transactional, you'd need to implement [SessionAwareMessageListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SessionAwareMessageListener.html). The onMessage method in this case gives you a handle on Session object. You'd then need to either do a session.commit(){If the business logic was executed properly} or session.rollback(){If there was an error; Usually this is done in catch blocks}

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I have rollback the session and also i to make sessionTransacted property true in order to make it transnational and it is working fine for me now.